# Svn commit in PHP

Tags: php, svn

I have an a script which generate some keys. This script must commit them on svn-server. They are different. Can you help me with some idea?

I think about svn php lib and system / exec, but don't know how connect with svn-server and save file there.

P.S. More about question. It was impossible. Our production server deployed from SVN repository and sometimes generates documents for accounts. We was need to save them in our repository, which closed from production for writing. So we use another way. Sorry for disappointing.

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you're asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Before you start, check out a fresh copy of the repository. SVN will remember the server and automatically save all your committed stuff there.

```
$ svn co svn-server/path/to/repo /path/to/working/copy
```

You can commit all files in a specific path, with a specific commit message using the svn client and the exec() method. I would be using this as long as the subversion bindings for PHP aren't stable:

```
<?php
  /* To commit all files in /path/to/working/copy */
  $message="'This is my commit message'";
  $command = "svn ci -q -m $message /path/to/working/copy";

  exec($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

SVN lib is very simple. Firstly, set username and password

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, 'username');
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, 'password');
svn_update(realpath('working-copy'));
//TODO: change files in working copy
var_dump(svn_commit('Changelog', array(realpath('working-copy'))));
```

If you don't have working-copy use `svn_checkout`

Answer (score 0):

See the following [SVN functions in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.svn.php)

[svn_commit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-commit.php) is one of them ...

**Note**

> This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.